# What is the suggested viewing order of The Disappearance of Eleanor Rigby: Her, Him and Them?

Tags: suggested-order, the-disappearance-of-eleanor-rigby

I am planning to watch *The Disappearance of Eleanor Rigby*. I have *Him, Her and Them*.

What is the suggested viewing order?

Comment: [Them has the two separate films edited into a linear story; this is the version used for DVD and Blu-ray releases and broadcasting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Disappearance_of_Eleanor_Rigby)

Comment: Seems odd this is off-topic, yet the sidebar shows several very similar questions that were well-received. As the first 2 movies were released simultaneously, all you really have to go on is 'convention'. They're always listed as Him, then Her; so without opinion-based discussion, one could assume that would be the "correct order". Them is a year later so presumably everyone could accept that should be third.

Comment: @Tetsujin my bad.  I think it was the use of 'prefer' in the question, I didn't realize there could be a relatively objective order.

Comment: @iandotkelly - no worries, all sorted :))

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Many thx. Do I understand correctly, I should see (only) "Them", then if I soo into it, just for curiosity the other two?

Comment: I'd be inclined to think of it in the same way as watching Memento. Unless you've seen the original version, the chronological version would make little sense. One would also imagine that 'Them' is more of a bite-sized cut down of the original pair, for easier consumption by a wider audience. if you want the full experience as the director intended, watch it last.

Comment: @Tetsujin Many thx. I have not seen yet any of them, so I do know nothing about the content, Memento is a great movie btw. I also do not know the director's intent that's why I am asking, before sitting down and watch. Based what you wrote, 'them' will be the last (and optional). Still the question remains, which first: 'Her', 'Him' or 'Does not matter'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://www.screendaily.com/the-disappearance-of-eleanor-rigby-him-and-her/5060433.article#:%7E:text=in%20Toronto%20it%20shows%20in%20both%20variations,%20though%20Him%20before%20Her%20is%20the%20most%20logical%20version), both variations have been screened but *Him* before *Her* is more logical.

*Them* is a condensed version of these two and is intended for the commercial release. But, it is not the same experience which the makers wanted the viewers to have. See [here](https://www.vulture.com/2014/09/the-disappearance-of-eleanor-rigby-3-versions-explainer.html#:%7E:text=We%20never%20intended%20for%20the%20film%20to%20be%20seen%20like%20that). If you do watch *Him* and *Her*, you may skip *Them* (totally upto you, as it does not add to the experience).

On a personal note, I watched *Him* before *Her* and also feel that this order was more appropriate.